# How many soldiers fought in the Mongol conquest of Song

Tags: war, mongol-empire, medieval-china

Wikipedia says the Mongols invaded the Song with an initial force of 90 tumens, or 900,000 soldiers at full strength. Considering the war lasted 44 years and the Mongols must have provided continuous reinforcements to their army, we could easily be talking millions or more, since 44 years is longer than almost any term of service.

The problem is there is almost no information on how many soldiers were fielded after the initial invasion. Were reinforcements supplied, did the frontline strength increase or decrease after the initial invasion? For reference, Operation Barbarossa involved an initial force of 3,800,000 soldiers, while the total that fought was 28,000,000, and that's just four years. By the same proportion, the Mongols would have fielded more than six million men.

So my question is how many ***total*** men were involved in the entire 44 year course of the Mongol conquest of Song?

This is an almost impossible question to answer, so any specific information that might make an estimate easier would be helpful. For example:

- A list of the number of soldiers fielded in various battles
- The number of soldiers fielded by the Mongols at any point after the initial invasion
- The largest number of soldiers ever fielded in a single battle.
- The number of soldiers fielded by the Song

For the last one, I remember hearing the Song fielded 3,200,000 soldiers, but I have since been unable to find where I first heard it, I don't know the source, and if it is true I don't know whether this was at one point in time or over the entire war.

Comment: Take all figures from ancient time with a grain of salt, authors were often hyperbolic to emphasize large numbers. Also, consider that Mongols often used Han troops ( "Han army" and "Newly Submitted Army") .

Comment: In my experience the most reliable sources, especially primary sources, are usually spot on, while as time goes on they get more and more distorted. For example, Rashid al-Din gives 600-700,000 Mongol soldiers in the invasion of Kwharazmia, and the paper I read makes a pretty compelling case that this is exactly right. On the other hand, he gives at most 30,000 Mongols at the Battle of Mohi, while other sources inflate this as high as 200,000. Since China was able to gather very large armies, the impression I have gotten from my reading is the best policy is take most numbers at face value ...

Comment: unless directly contradicted. For the purposes of this question, I will accept any numbers given by sources from that time. I'm not really interested in whether they're exaggerated or not.

Comment: Considering the logistic capabilities of Mongols and contemporary technology, 600-700 000 soldiers is too much. Most other sources mention 100 000 troops or below, which was still huge army for the period.

Comment: I hear people say things like "Considering the logistic capabilities," or "contemporary technology," all the time, but they never give any explanation beyond that. Things like logistics are often used as just buzzwords. If you could give me a specific argument for why that many soldiers is too much, I would be happy to listen, but just saying "logistics" without any further elaboration doesn't prove anything.

Comment: You have X soldiers (plus their horses) have you going to feed them ? Each solider could carry food for a few days (maybe even week or two) but what to do later ? You could carry (drive) supplies with you, but how big would your logistic tail be ? You could plunder food in occupied country, but would capturing few villages (around thousand inhabitants) , maybe some town with 5000 inhabitants, be enough for an army of 700 000 ?

Comment: But everything you just said applies to 100,000 or 10,000 as well. You have to explain specifically why it is impossible to feed that many people. Just saying "It's hard" doesn't mean anything. If you're going to say it's impossible, you need a specific argument. For example, "700,000 soldiers is impossible because that many soldiers can't march through such and such defile in the amount of time they supposedly marched through."

Comment: No, it does not. With 10 000 soldiers, you could bring with you few hundred heads of cattle (to be meat on hoofs) and each village you plunder would bring enough food and fodder for at least half a day. With 100 000 soldiers you are already in trouble. In fact, as far as I know, Mongols would never march in groups larger than 20-30 000. If they had larger army, they would divide it and take different directions trough enemy countryside.